# Убрать авто-генерацию кнопок

Tags: php, tpl

Здравствуйте уважаемы участники!
Прошу помощи, возможно кто то знает как убрать с шаблона (авто подставку кнопок к блоку что бы заменить их статическими кнопками и ссылками) так как количество блоков не генерируется а статично указано в коде.
Код блоков (в которые подставляются некоторые значения ! И сами кнопки.
`

```
        {$items = [
            [
                'title' => 'Test',
                'price' => '9',
                'id' => '16',
                'color' => '',
                'mobile' => [
                    'title' => 'TEst',
                    'desc1' => 'Test',
                    'desc2' => 'TEst'
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    ['name' => 'Процессор', 'value' => '1 x 2.6 ГГц'],
                    ['name' => 'Память', 'value' => '1024 Мб'],
                    ['name' => 'Диск', 'value' => '30 Гб'],
                    ['name' => 'Поддержка 24/7', 'value' => ''],
                    ['name' => 'Установка OC Бесплатно', 'value' => '']
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Test',
                'price' => '16',
                'id' => '20',
                'color' => 'recommended',
                'mobile' => [
                    'title' => 'Test',
                    'desc1' => 'TEst',
                    'desc2' => 'TEst'
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    ['name' => 'Процессор', 'value' => '1 x 2.6 ГГц'],
                    ['name' => 'Память', 'value' => '2048 Мб'],
                    ['name' => 'Диск', 'value' => '60 Гб'],
                    ['name' => 'Поддержка 24/7', 'value' => ''],
                    ['name' => 'Установка OC Бесплатно', 'value' => '']
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Test',
                'price' => '35',
                'id' => '21',
                'color' => '',
                'mobile' => [
                    'title' => 'Test',
                    'desc1' => 'TEst',
                    'desc2' => 'Test'
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    ['name' => 'Процессор', 'value' => '2 x 2.6 ГГц'],
                    ['name' => 'Память', 'value' => '4096 Мб'],
                    ['name' => 'Диск', 'value' => '100 Гб'],
                    ['name' => 'Поддержка 24/7', 'value' => ''],
                    ['name' => 'Установка OC Бесплатно', 'value' => '']
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'TEst',
                'price' => '70',
                'id' => '22',
                'color' => '',
                'mobile' => [
                    'title' => 'TEst',
                    'desc1' => 'TEst',
                    'desc2' => 'TEst'
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    ['name' => 'Процессор', 'value' => '4 x 2.6 ГГц'],
                    ['name' => 'Память', 'value' => '8 Гб'],
                    ['name' => 'Диск', 'value' => '150 Гб'],
                    ['name' => 'Поддержка 24/7', 'value' => ''],
                    ['name' => 'Установка OC Бесплатно', 'value' => '']
                ]
            ]
        ]}

        {include file="$template/includes/pricing-table.tpl" id='2'}

    </div>`
```

Код который выводит

```
 <div id="carousel{$id}" class="carousel">
    {foreach item=i from=$items}
        <div class="pricing-table carousel-element {$i.color}">
            <h3 class="pricing-title">{$i.title}</h3>
            <ul class="table-list">
                {foreach item=p from=$i.properties}
                    <li>{$p.name}{if $p.value}: {$p.value}{/if}</li>
                {/foreach}
            </ul>
            <div class="price">{$i.price_prev}${$i.price}<sup>/ мес</sup></div>
            <div class="table-buy">
                <a class="btn" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/cart.php?a=add&pid={$i.id}"><span>Заказать</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

Тип страниц Tpl.
Буду благодарен помощи каждого!

Comment: `<a class="btn" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/cart.php?a=add&pid={$i.id}"><span>Заказать</span></a>` просто в href подставляете свою ссылку. Можно дурблировать `a` и будет вам 2 кнопки

Comment: Здравствуйте дело в том, что код который подставляет кнопки он используется на разных страницах, в том числе на той на которой нужно убрать эти кнопки и заменить их (четырьма такими же просто с моими статично вписаными ссылками в них)
Если же просто в документе продублировать "<a class="btn" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/cart.php?a=add&pid={$i.id}"><span>Заказать</span></a>" и заменить ссылку, то на всех страницах добавляется новая кнопка и на всех блоках одна и та же ссылка будет. 
Увы этот вариант не подходит. Благодарю вас!

Comment: Так заведите переменную... вот у вас есть `$items`, сделайте вторую, например `$myButton = TRUE` (условно), а в шаблоне проверку: если есть переменная `$myButton` то выводим вашу кастомную конпку, иначе ту, что есть сейчас... Тогда ничего не сломается